# Downloading files with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I want to download lots (dozens to thousands, depending on use-case) of files from different locations on a server. All the files are about 0.1MB to 1MB in size. The download is supposed to be happening in an asynchronous manner. I have working code (see below) which I would like to optimize.

I tried to come up with a solution using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. I am still a bit confused by all this and trying to understand how this really works.

My questions regarding the code below are:

1. How do I resume a download if it fails in an elegant way using the capabilities of the applied modules? (I mostly got this error: `Cannot connect to host ftp.server.net:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]`)
2. Do you see potential to simplify this code somehow?
3. Any suggestions on making it more stable?
4. Is there any other option you would recommend?

This is my code:

```
async def download_file(session, url):
    try:
        async with sem:
            with async_timeout.timeout(100):
                async with session.get(url) as remotefile:
                    if remotefile.status == 200:
                        data = await remotefile.read()
                        return {"error": "", "data": data}
                    else:
                        print(url)
                        return {"error": remotefile.status, "data": ""}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": e, "data": ""}

async def store_file(session, work_queue):
    while not work_queue.empty():
        queue_url = await work_queue.get()
        data = await download_file(session, queue_url)
        filename = queue_url.split('/')[-1]
        if not data["error"]:
            filepath = assemb_path+"/"+filename
            with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(data["data"])
        else:
            print(data["error"])

async def download_queue(urls):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    q = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
    [q.put_nowait(url) for url in urls]
    con = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=10) # number concurent downloads
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop, connector=con) as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(store_file(session, q)) for _ in range(len(urls))]
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    loop.close()

sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)
nest_asyncio.apply()
# perform the actual download:
asyncio.run(download_queue(list(map(lambda x: re.sub("^ftp", "https", x[0]+"/"+x[1]), download_list))))
```